# How to use a variable from $.get()

Tags: jquery

Kindly take a look at $.get().  I need to use the variable nextId in the subsequent $.post() but having the problem of being undefined outside the scope of $.get()

```
$('#addbtn').click(function(){

    var insname = $('#ins').val();
    var itemexist = false;

    $.each($('#selname option'), function(key, value){
        if($(this).text() == $.trim(insname)){
            itemexist = true;
            alert("Item already exists: "+$(this).text());
        }
    });

    if(insname=='') alert("Cannot be empty");

    if(!itemexist && insname!='') {

        $.get('data1.php',

            function(retId){
                var nextId = retId;
                var incrementlength = 1;
                incrementlength+= $('#selname option').length;

                $('#selname').attr('size',incrementlength);
                $('#selname')
                    .append($('<option></option>')
                    .attr('value', nextId).text(insname));
                $('#ins').val('');
            });

        alert(nextId);//nextId is not defined
        $.post('data1_1.php', {id: nextId, name: insname},);
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens here is that the `nextId` is set during an asynchronous callback, so when you are calling the alert, `nextId` is undefined, because it hasn't been set yet. If you want to use the returned `nextId` in the `$.post()` you will have to call the `$.post()` after the `$.get()` callback completes. Modify your code as below and it should work:

Try this:

```
$('#addbtn').click(function(){

    var insname = $('#ins').val();
    var itemexist = false;

    $.each($('#selname option'), function(key, value){

        if($(this).text() == $.trim(insname)){
            itemexist = true;
            alert("Item already exists: "+$(this).text());
        }
        });

        if(insname=='') alert("Cannot be empty");
        if(!itemexist && insname!=''){
        $.get('data1.php',
                function(retId){
                    var nextId = retId;
            var incrementlength = 1;
            incrementlength+= $('#selname option').length;
            $('#selname').attr('size',incrementlength);
            $('#selname').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', nextId).text(insname));
            $('#ins').val('');
            alert(nextId);//nextId should be defined
            $.post('data1_1.php',
                    {id: nextId, name: insname},
                    );
            }
        });


});
```

Comment: Yes, at stackoverflow the answer that implies less thinking for OP almost always wins, lol

Comment: Er... I'm new at contributing to SO. I was previously mostly a read and leave type. I wasn't aware of any requirement that answers were supposed to make the askers think. I just provided the best (IMO) answer I could.

Comment: @asleepysamurai: sure, nothing personal ;-) But 1) you've given wrong result at first attempt 2) as adverb says: "Give a man a fish; you have fed him for today. Teach a man to fish; and you have fed him for a lifetime"

Comment: Thank you so much.I did try declaring it outside to make global but I didn't know the part (nextId = retId, without the var declaration)

Comment: @zerk that may be true, but your answer still have more upvotes. (one from me of course) :-)

Comment: @zerkms & eddy: Yeah sorry about the first answer, I din't read the code properly and rushed off with an answer. My bad.

Comment: @asleepysamurai: that's okay. Changed -1 to +1

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: not now ;-) Changed -1 to +1 since asleepysamurai is new here and seems like he is really good guy ;-) And of course because he's given right answer.

Comment: @zerk right now you have 4 while Mr. Sleepy has only 3.. I guess that gold badge is luring people to upvote you! :-D

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: argh!!!! It never happens when I really need my answer upvoted ;-)

Comment: @zerk yep, Murphy's law in its full glory. ;)

Comment: Hardly noticed your revision, been thinking of how to make it all in a single $.get() as zerkms have said.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

That is because `$.get` is performed asynchronously (that is what `A` in `AJAX` means)

You can:

1. Change the `$.get` to `$.ajax` and make it synchronous with `async: false` option
2. (preferred) To perform all your work in `$.get` callback

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I was thinking of your number 2(preferred) reply.how would I do that?I used $.get to fetch max(id) and used it together with input text to append to a select list. I was trying to use $.post to store the key/value to a db.Thank you again for the help.

Comment: @eddy: #2 is what exactly proposed @asleepysamurai in his answer.

Comment: my mistake..i didn't notice it was revised by sleepysamurai. I got of learning to do i never thought $.get and $.post could be nested. I was cracking my head on how to stuff it all in a single $.get as in your reply.Thanks again