# How to get the value of a variable from a callback of jQuery.post?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use the return value(response) from the callback outside the jQuery.post API..how can that be done?

```
jQuery.post( ajaxurl, 'action', function( response ) 
{
console.log(response); // this comes back with "working"

// i tried this responseVal = response;  but didn't work            

}); 

alert(response); // this will be undefined.
```

So I want the alert to have access to response....Yes I know I could easily alerted it inside the callback but my application needs to access this outside.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ajax methods are asynchronous, they start executing and then program continues doing what it was doing. An alert right after the ajax method might (probably will) happen before the ajax method even completes. So it's going to be undefined because it hasnt been populated yet, even with a global variable. Use the success callback to trigger whichever action must come next

Comment: @xander sorry, I'm not following. I see the scope issue you pointed out, but that doesn't change the fact that it's asynchronous and would fail anyway

Comment: @nbrooks - how do i go about adding the complete function you mentioned?

Comment: the global ajax listener undefined mentions in his answer is a reasonable way of doing it. It is triggered whenever an ajax call succeeds, so be careful with your scope. http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/

Comment: Search stack overflow. **There are already too many duplicates of this.** (-1)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904376/in-jquery-post-how-do-i-get-value-of-variable-outside-function?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447875/how-to-use-a-variable-from-get?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946711/how-to-get-the-value-from-a-callback-function?rq=1 **and etc.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That callback is asynchronous, so execution in your js proceeds without waiting for response to be set.  In all likelihood, `responseVal = response` would *not happen* by the time the `alert(responseVal)` fires, so responseVal would be unset.

You can test this by initializing `responseVal` to some obviously "not set" value, doing the ajax call, alerting, wasting time in your script (like `while(responseVal == "not set") { i++; }`) and then alerting again.

I know your question says you can't make whatever use of `response` you need to in the success callback, but I suggest you *try harder to figure out how to do so* else you'll be dealing with `setInterval(...)` shenanigans ala @Xander's answer or setting the `async=false` option in [`jQuery.ajax(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (along with making that request a post and setting the url, etc) and holding up execution.

Comment: What would the code look like to set async to false on jQuery.post?

Comment: @Rick: apologies, it appears you can only use that option with the full `jQuery.ajax` instead of the shortcut `jQuery.post`.  Editing reply accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`response` is out of scope when you call alert.

The following snippet executes a function that checks whether `result` has been set and if so clears the interval and alerts `result`:

```
var result, interval;

jQuery.post( ajaxurl, 'action', function( response ) 
{
    result = response;
}); 

interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(result !== undefined) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        alert(result); 
    }
}, 1000);
```